# Find out who su'ed to your user

Tags: linux, su

We are using Suse linux in our company, and I was wondering if there anyway I can get an alert whenever someone use 'su' command in order to switch to my linux user? Do you have any idea how this can be implemented?

Thanks.

Comment: By sending yourself an email every time you log in, from `.bash_login`? Or doing something else there or in `.bashrc` that may grab your attention. Alternatively ask the root users to inform you.

Comment: `su` uses pam and therefore (should) generate log messages about its doings. Usually the information you are looking for can be retrieved from the logfiles. Sometimes in files like `/var/log/secure`, but I don't know how SuSe works. You could `grep` for "session opened" to find the log entries I am talking about.

Answer (score 3):

the standard linux reports su and sudo usage is via the PAM module in `/var/log/auth.log`.

So the easiest way is to track this log file and create alarms. You can build just a simple script to send out mails or use log file analyzers ( i.e. logstash, graylog ) which are able to trigger alarms.

Here are two examples of `su` and `sudo` usage protocols:

user: testx successfully got root by using the `su` command at 07:47:26 and exited again at 07:47:30

```
May 11 07:47:26 server su[3873]: Successful su for root by testx
May 11 07:47:26 server su[3873]: + /dev/pts/3 testx:root
May 11 07:47:26 server su[3873]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by testx(uid=1002)
May 11 07:47:30 server su[3873]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
```

user: testx successfully got root by using the `sudo` command at 07:54:21 and exited again at 07:54:31

```
May 11 07:54:21 server sudo:    testx : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/sh
May 11 07:54:21 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by testx(uid=0)
May 11 07:54:31 server sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

user: testx is not allowed to use `sudo` command (unsucessful try).

```
May 11 07:56:04 server sudo:    testx : user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/sh
```

user: text is not allowed to use `su` command (wrong password).

```
May 11 07:56:57 server su[3927]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname=testx uid=1002 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/3 ruser=testx rhost=  user=root
May 11 07:56:59 server su[3927]: pam_authenticate: Authentication failure
May 11 07:56:59 server su[3927]: FAILED su for root by testx
May 11 07:56:59 server su[3927]: - /dev/pts/3 testx:root
```